# How to convert Apfloat to BigDecimal?

Tags: java, apfloat

I am using the following code where `k` is a `BigDecimal`:

```
Apfloat power = ApfloatMath.pow(new Apfloat(-1), new Apfloat(k));
```

`Apfloat` seems to have methods like `intValue()`, `doubleValue()`, `floatValue()` but I can't see how I can convert `Apfloat` to `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention the docs are at: http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/docs/org/apfloat/Apfloat.html

Comment: The only trivial way of doing this I can find is converting the `Apfloat` to a string (since it is `Formattable`) and then constructing a new `BigDecimal` from that string. Dunno if the string you get is usable, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigDecimals are best generated from Strings or using the `BigDecimal.valueOf( double)` static constructor.

For your specific requirement, start with the following:

```
public static asBigDecimal (Apfloat val) {
    return BigDecimal.valueOf( val.doubleValue());
}
```

Calling `new BigDecimal(double)` is specifically to be avoided, since it generates *exact* decimal representations of the floating-point bits & can somewhat unpredictably require vast numbers of decimal digits to do so.

On the other hand, `BigDecimal.valueOf( double)` and `Double.toString( double)` have specific logic to represent doubles -> decimal without spurious deep decimalization.

See:

- `java.math.BigDecimal.BigDecimal(double)`

Quoting from the Javadoc:

The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable.
One might assume that writing `new BigDecimal(0.1)` in
Java creates a `BigDecimal` which is exactly equal to
0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with a scale of 1), but it is
actually equal to 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625.
This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a
`double` (or, for that matter, as a binary fraction of
any finite length).  Thus, the value that is being passed
*in* to the constructor is not exactly equal to 0.1,
appearances notwithstanding.